# Oracle SQL select sum from last 30 days showing actual day

Tags: sql, oracle, select

It sounds like a weird query, but the concept is pretty simple, just that I can't figure out how to achieve it.

My actual table is similar to this one:

| YEAR | MONTH | DAY | DATE | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 2 | 22 | 2023/02/22 | 50 |
| 2023 | 2 | 21 | 2023/02/21 | 150 |

And I would like to create a view where each day shows the value of last 30 days.

I achieved something similar using "Over Order by rows between", but now we need to show exactly 30 last, not our last 30 rows.

```
select 
t3.year_, 
t3.month_, 
t3.day_, 
sum(t3.V1) over (order by to_date(t3.year_||lpad(t3.month_,2,'0')||lpad(t3.day_,2,'0'),'yyyymmdd') rows between 29 preceding and current row) as VALUE_LAST_30, 
from (select t2.year_,t2.month_,t2.day_ 
    sum(value_) as V1
    from table1 t2
    group by t2.year_,t2.month_,t2.day_) t3
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How "exactly 30 last" differs from "our last 30" rows?

Comment: Do you mean that for each day you wish to have 30 columns for the last 30 days before that day? Or what? I understand that "exactly 30 last"  would mean date>=x.date-30 and not "the last 30 rows", which may be before x.date-30 because during the last 30 days there are days where you have no value.

Comment: @Littlefoot The difference in this situation is because not every day has values saved, for example not on weekends, and we must this value always between two known dates.

Comment: I think you just need to change your `rows between` to `range between`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you wish to get the sum(value) for the last 30 days, then I'd say something like below

```
select t.x_date, t.value
  ,(select sum(t2.value) 
  from table_1 t2
  where t2.x_date between t.x_date-30 and t.x_date) value_30_days
from table_1 t;
```

Comment: I was able to adapt your solution in my table with a few changes in date columns. I knew it was not hard, but I was stuck and I was unable to find the answer. Thanks!